# XQuery find XMLs which have two /X/@A with the values of "1" and "2" respectively

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

I have the following XMLs. And I need to get the XML which `X` has the attribute `A` with both values of `1` and `2`.

```
with    t as ( select   cast(x as xml) x
               from     ( values ( 'Test'), 
                        ( '<X A="1">xxx</X>'), 
                        ( '<X A="1">xxx</X><X A="2">xxx</X>') ) as t ( x )
               )
    select  *
    from    t
```

I can use the following SQL to get the XML which exists `X` with both `@A = "1"` and `@A = "2"` (`<X A="1">xxx</X><X A="2">xxx</X>`).

```
with    t as ( select   cast(x as xml) x
               from     ( values ( 'Test'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X>'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X><X A="2">xxx</X>') ) as t ( x )
               )
    select  *
    from    t
    where x.exist('/X[@A = "1"]') = 1 and x.exist('/X[@A = "2"]') = 1;
```

Is it possible to write **only one** XQuery for it? The following SQL doesn't work. It returns all three XMLs.

```
with    t as ( select   cast(x as xml) x
               from     ( values ( 'Test'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X>'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X><X A="2">xxx</X>') ) as t ( x )
               )
    select  *
    from    t
    where x.exist('/X[@A = "1"] and /X[@A = "2"]') = 1;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `xmls` there are xml `nodes` (or `elements`),  which you can query with Xpath based on their position in a tree. You should clean this up and provide sample input,  query,  and expected output, if you want people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. `data(/X/@A) = "1"` will return true if `data(/X/@A)` contains `1`.

```
with    t as ( select   cast(x as xml) x
               from     ( values ( 'Test'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X>'), ( '<X A="1">xxx</X><X A="2">xxx</X>') ) as t ( x )
               )
    select  *
    from    t
    where x.exist('.[data(/X/@A)="1" and data(/X/@A)="2"]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `/X[@A = "1"] and /X[@A = "2"]` cannot be true. You are asking a same element to have 2 values in the same time. It's like looking for a Mr. John whose name is Mr. Jack.

Depending on how you will generalize your example (more than 2 `<X>` elements , incremental values for `@A`, etc. ?), there might be different possible answers.

Could you be more specific in the use case ?

Comment: `exist(/X[@A = "1"] and /X[@A = "2"])` is actually true for all the three rows. I guess you meant `/X[@A = "1" and @A = "2"]`. The reason is for permance tuning - I want to reduce the xml queries.

Comment: You want to compare the static sequence `('1', '2')` with the dynamic sequence `/X/A/data()`.
Not sure how to "deep-compare" two sequences without a function though, like such function : http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_sequence-deep-equal.html
`=` does not deep-compare sequences like this code proves it :
    let $a := <a>
      <X A="1">xxx</X>
      <X A="2">xxx</X>
    </a>
    let $b := $a/X/@A/data()
    let $c := ('1','2')
    return if ( $b = $c) then 'same sequence!' else 'diff. sequence !'

Answer (score 0):

xpath: `root/X[@A = (1, 2)]` 
does the trick for me

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kg/1

Comment: `X[@A = (1, 2)]` will return true for either 1 or 2. In my case, it will return the last two xmls instead of the last one.

Comment: yes it returns both elements since that is what you indicated in your question `which X has the attribute A with both values of 1 and 2`. No mention of `last`. If you want something else,  please rephrase your question,  or open a new one.